# Syntax error at or near "ON" when using ON CONFLICT

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, unique-constraint, upsert

I have a table `artist` that has a unique constraint on `song_id`. I want to ensure that insert doesn't throw an error when running. I have written the code below but I was getting the error stated below.

```sql
TRUNCATE artists;
INSERT INTO artists (song_id, title, artist_id, year, duration)
SELECT distinct song_id, title, artist_id, year, duration FROM staging_songs
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

The error is `ERROR: syntax error at or near "ON"`

Comment: Your code is fine (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dd14fea0b9e3eafacc437ab88315fa80).  Perhaps you are using an old version of Postgres.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c93a79b48fd1ef9521411a2f3c2d9709)

Comment: What does `select version();` give you?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name PostgreSQL 8.0.2 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 3.4.2 20041017 (Red Hat 3.4.2-6.fc3), Redshift 1.0.27747

Comment: you are not using Postgres, you are using Amazon Redhshift. So you should be checking the [Redshift manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/cm_chap_SQLCommandRef.html)  if you are looking for a command. Redshift's INSERT simply [does not support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html) `on conflict`

Comment: You should make that comment into the answer, @a_horse_with_no_name.